# The problem of sending more than 4 TPDO using CANopenNode

Tags: canopen

I've been using the CANopenNode stack recently. When I used CANopenNode on stm32, I found that the problem occurred when I sent five TPDO(TPDO1~TPDO5):

1. After starting, PDO1~TPDO4 were automatically sent, but TPDO5 was not sent. When I was running at the breakpoints, all TPdos could be sent out normally;
2. If the timer is used to trigger the sending of TPDO5, an error will occur: CAN overrun. Then the node changes to the Pre-operationa state

error pic：[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnPGu.png)

nomarl send running at the breakpoints:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ7iW.png)

nomarl send pic:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfdRN.png)

I've changed here in CO_PDO.h based on the comment:

```
    /** Number of CANopen TPDO objects, which uses default CAN indentifiers.
     * If value is more than four, then pre-defined pre-defined CAN identifiers are:
     * TPDO5 has CAN_ID=0x180+NodeId+1, TPDO6 has CAN_ID=0x280+NodeId+1,
     * TPDO9 has CAN_ID=0x180+NodeId+2 and so on.
     * For description see @ref CO_RPDO_DEFAULT_CANID_COUNT. */
    #ifndef CO_TPDO_DEFAULT_CANID_COUNT
    #define CO_TPDO_DEFAULT_CANID_COUNT 5
    #endif
```

Here is part of my dictionary file OD.c:

```
    .x1800_TPDOCommunicationParameter = {
        .highestSub_indexSupported = 0x06,
        .COB_IDUsedByTPDO = 0x40000180,
        .transmissionType = 0xFE,
        .inhibitTime = 0x0000,
        .eventTimer =  0x0,
        .SYNCStartValue = 0x00
    },
    .x1801_TPDOCommunicationParameter = {
        .highestSub_indexSupported = 0x06,
        .COB_IDUsedByTPDO = 0x40000280,
        .transmissionType = 0xFE,
        .inhibitTime = 0x0000,
        .eventTimer =  0x0,
        .SYNCStartValue = 0x00
    },
    .x1802_TPDOCommunicationParameter = {
        .highestSub_indexSupported = 0x06,
        .COB_IDUsedByTPDO = 0x40000380,
        .transmissionType = 0xFE,
        .inhibitTime = 0x0000,
        .eventTimer =  0x0,
        .SYNCStartValue = 0x00
    },
    .x1803_TPDOCommunicationParameter = {
        .highestSub_indexSupported = 0x06,
        .COB_IDUsedByTPDO = 0x40000480,
        .transmissionType = 0xFE,
        .inhibitTime = 0x0000,
        .eventTimer =  0x0,
        .SYNCStartValue = 0x00
    },
    .x1804_TPDOCommunicationParameter = {
        .highestSub_indexSupported = 0x06,
        .COB_IDUsedByTPDO = 0x40000180,
        .transmissionType = 0xFE,
        .inhibitTime = 0x0000,
        .eventTimer = 0x0,
        .SYNCStartValue = 0x00
    },
    .x1A00_TPDOMappingParameter = {
        .numberOfMappedApplicationObjectsInPDO = 0x01,
        .applicationObject1 = 0x20000020,
        .applicationObject2 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject3 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject4 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject5 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject6 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject7 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject8 = 0x00000000
    },
    .x1A01_TPDOMappingParameter = {
        .numberOfMappedApplicationObjectsInPDO = 0x01,
        .applicationObject1 = 0x20010020,
        .applicationObject2 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject3 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject4 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject5 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject6 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject7 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject8 = 0x00000000
    },
    .x1A02_TPDOMappingParameter = {
        .numberOfMappedApplicationObjectsInPDO = 0x01,
        .applicationObject1 = 0x20020020,
        .applicationObject2 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject3 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject4 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject5 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject6 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject7 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject8 = 0x00000000
    },
    .x1A03_TPDOMappingParameter = {
        .numberOfMappedApplicationObjectsInPDO = 0x01,
        .applicationObject1 = 0x20030020,
        .applicationObject2 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject3 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject4 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject5 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject6 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject7 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject8 = 0x00000000
    },
    .x1A04_TPDOMappingParameter = {
        .numberOfMappedApplicationObjectsInPDO = 0x01,
        .applicationObject1 = 0x20040020,
        .applicationObject2 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject3 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject4 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject5 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject6 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject7 = 0x00000000,
        .applicationObject8 = 0x00000000
    },
    .x2000_PMM_battery = 0x11111111,
    .x2001_PMM_temp = 0x22222222,
    .x2002_PMM_time = 0x33333333,
    .x2003_PMM_current = 0x44444444,
    .x2004_PMM_voltage = 0x55555555
```

1. I don't know what causes this problem.  When there are more than 4 TPDO, should i need to set other Settings?
2. Why are all TPDO automatically sent once after startup?
   (In addition: baud rate is 1M)

Comment: I'm using step debugging to debug the code, I find all TPDO will send once since startup, it's normal situation. But my TPDO5 was't being sent,it's so werid